# How to remove list elements without an additional for loop?

Tags: apex, list, loop

I need to remove from the following `revenueList` list all elements where `newRevenueDate` is NULL without any additional for loops.

```
List<Revenue__c> revenueWithNoDateList = new List<Revenue__c>();
    for(Revenue__c revenue : revenueList) {
        Date newRevenueDate = revenue.Revenue_Date__c;
        if(newRevenueDate == null) {
            //get all revenue records with no date
            revenueWithNoDateList.add(revenue);
        }
    }
```

How can I possibly do that?

Comment: There seems to be information missing from your question, and this also seems to be something of an interview question. How is `revenueList` populated to begin with? Why, exactly, is using this tight loop not an option? Without knowing the full picture, the best anyone will be able to do is guess at what your true goal is, and make a shot-in-the-dark answer. The answers you'll get may be right in some situations, but how sure are you that it'd be right in your situation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could possibly use `while` loop instead of `for` loop. By doing so, you can have two lists, one with the values where `Revenue_Date__c` is `null` and other original one which will contain only the records where `Revenue_Date__c` is `not null` as you will be removing the elements where `Revenue_Date__c` is `null`.

Here is the code to do so

```
List<Revenue__c> revenueWithNoDateList = new List<Revenue__c>();
Integer i = 0;
while (i < revenueList.size()){
    if(revenueList.get(i).Revenue_Date__c == null){
        revenueWithNoDateList.add(revenueList.get(i));
        revenueList.remove(i);
    } else {
        i++;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

In this context, you cannot. If you were to try, you would receive

> System.FinalException: Cannot modify a collection while it is being iterated.

In most programming languages, it is problematic to mutate a collection while you are iterating over it. Here, you will need to create a new `List<Revenue__c>` and add only elements matching your criteria to it, while iterating over `revenueList` - just like you do here with `revenueWithNoDateList`.

There is not a way to do this in Apex without the use of iteration. If you traverse the loop using an index variable rather than an iterator, you can remove items using the `List.remove(index)` method to achieve an in-place filtering, but you'll need to be careful to adjust your `for` logic accordingly to avoid index out of bounds errors.

Comment: +1 though... "avoid index out of bounds errors" *and skipping records*.